# How to use 'chown' on a mounted file system

Tags: bash, filesystems, embedded-linux, mount, chown

I have a root filesystem, RFS1, that has its own groups and users and is currently being used by the kernel.

I mount another root filesystem, RFS2, which has its own groups and users. How can I run [chown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown) on a file/directory under RFS2 to create an owner from within the groups listed under */etc/groups* of RFS2?

I am executing the *chown* while the OS (Linux) is using RFS1.

Comment: If you know what the IDs are for users on RFS2, then you can use them with [`chown`](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chown.1.html). `chown` accepts user IDs: `chown 123 filespec....` or for groups, too: `chown 123:200 filespec...`.

Comment: I have the groupid and username. the groupadd and useradd create group and user succssfully inside the RFS2 and makes entries inside the /etc/group and /etc/passwd of RFS2. But the chown when executed checks if the group and owner is present inside the etc/group of RFS1 and does not check for etc/group of RFS2.

Comment: That's interesting. Never realized that about `useradd` and `groupadd`. I actually would have expected them to use the designated system driveu. Isn't the password file for RFS2 something like `/mount-path/etc/passwd`? I don't see any options in `chown` to select a different drive, so you may have to use the raw IDs.

Comment: Useradd and groups have the option of -R for changed root directory. Sadly chosen does not. I have the groupid and username. Would it work out? As I mentioned this id would be inside rfs2 and not inside rfs1.

Comment: Ah, I missed that `-R` option. You can get the userid from the RFS2 password file given the username (you could use `sed` or `grep` and `cut` if you wanted to do so programmatically). Then you can use both the groupid and userid in `chown`. Or, maybe you could do `chroot` to RFS2, do your `chown` the way you want to, then `chroot` back to RFS1.

Comment: I am not sure of exact steps to execute chroot. Jailed directory creation could pose problems with mounted device as it would have its own set of binaries too.  The groupid is known already. But will it be enough to execute the chown coomand. Doesn't chown verify these numbers from config files of current RFS ??

Comment: 1. You can specify GID/UID in chown
2. You can sync UID and GID on two servers (or more).
3. If you have multiple servers, maybe you need to setup external centralized authorization solution like ldap or MS AD and configure linux to use it, so you will have "global users"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to chown RFS2 files to an RFS2 user, you don't need RFS1 for the chown, so the most straightforward way is [chroot(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chroot).

You mount RFS2 e.g. on `/mnt/rfs2`. Then you chroot into the target `/mnt/rfs2` as instructed [here](https://blog.coffeebeans.at/archives/263).

`chroot` creates a new process that is jailed within `/mnt/rfs2`. When that process refers to `/`, the OS will translate it as `/mnt/rfs2`. If the process refers to `/hello/world`, the OS will tranlsate it as `/mnt/rfs2/hello/world`.

If RFS2 has its own users, then it has its own `/etc/passwd`, and it's fair to assume it has it's own `/bin/`, `/usr/lib/` etc.

Once chrooted, make sure that your [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) matches where the binaries actually are.

Within the chroot jail, every command you execute, such as `chown`, will be searched in the `PATH`. It will probably be found in `/bin/chown`, but now that's RFS2's `/bin/chown` (namely `/mnt/rfs2/bin/chown`), not RFS1's. Every dynamic library that chown may be using will also come from the RFS2 filesystem.

When you `chown user:group`, `chown` will search the user and group in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`, but those are RFS2's passwd and group file.

Once you're done, you run `exit` and the jailed shell process that `chroot` created for you will exit. While all this was happening, the rest of the processes on the machine were still using RFS1.